# write a log message in eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, console, message

I know this has probably been asked already, but I still can't find a solution. I am testing a java class, and I would like to print a message in the Eclipse console to debbug my testing class (I've got errors).
I am currently trying this :

```
Log.debug("Before everything00000000000000000000000");
```

But it's not working...

How can I do this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write any message in console, simply use :

```
System.out.println(String msg)
```

`Logger` java class can also be used.

Comment: It doesnt work with System.out.println(String). However it is my first line in @Before
public void init()